# Is using a variables value as a default value in dict.get() a bad pattern?

Tags: python

I am currently writing some code which typically has the following pattern:

```
class Thing:
    defaults = {
        'on':1,
        'off': 0
    }
    def something(self, k, v):
        # if v is a key in the defaults, replace its value
        if v in self.defaults: 
            v = self.defaults[v]
        print(f'SET {k} {v}')
```

However, it's occured to me I can shorten the `if` statement by doing:

```
class Thing2:
    defaults = {
        'on':1,
        'off': 0
    }
    def something(self, k, v):
        v = self.defaults.get(v, v)
        print(f'SET {k} {v}')
```

It's handy, but is it a poor practice?

Comment: No, why would it be bad practice? However, no values are being replaced in either code.

Comment: I see no problem with using `get` here. One problem would be if you had to evaluate an expression (`get(v, v+3)`) or create a new object (`get(v, set())`) in order to pass a potentially unused value as the second argument, but that's not the case here. Really, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Okay thanks. To add a little more context, it's part of code to parse a simple custom scripting language which sets and test values for instrument sensors. It makes it easier for users to sometimes set default values for high/low/on/off/etc values in the tests and helps readability, but sometimes they're unique. Users can define `set tag on` and/or `set tag 0.02` which gets parsed in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to replace a generic if statement with a more specific conditional. It makes the intent clearer and more concise.

But you've also made a subtle type change here because your default keys and values are different. That can cause problems later.

For example, if you're setting `v = defaults.get(v, v)` and the default is present, you're changing it from a string to an integer. If you're treating them as just printable objects, that's fine. However, if you plan to go on to do calculations with them, it matters very much.

So ask the question: Am I changing the type of this thing? If the answer is yes, find another name. Otherwise it's fine.

Making that concrete, this is fine, you're printing printable things:

```
class Thing2:
    defaults = {
        'on':1,
        'off': 0
    }
    def something(self, k, v):
        v = self.defaults.get(v, v)
        print(f'SET {k} {v}')
```

This is not ok, you're changing the type

```
class Thing3:
    defaults = {
        'on':1,
        'off': 0
    }
    def something(self, k: int, v):
        v = self.defaults.get(v, v)
        return k + v

print("The total is: " + thing.something(10, 'on')) # TypeError probably
```

This is also ok, because the type doesn't change

```
class Thing4:
    defaults = {
        'on':"1"
        'off': "0"
    }
    def something(self, k, v):
        v = self.defaults.get(v, v)
        return k + v

print(thing.something('The result is: ' + 'on')
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question of `get` vs an explicit `if` statement.

Comment: @chepner I've updated it to address the general case first.